# Multiple Blog Pages

Tags: posts, blog-page

some Preview Sites of WP Premium Themes show Multiple Blog pages with different Templates as example.

a Full Width Blog Page
a Medium Image Blog Page
a Pinterest Style Blog Page.

Now how do they do that and have multiple "different" styled blog pages on one site?

Thanks,
Allan

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Codex page about creating your own page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).

> The files defining each Page Template are found in your Themes directory under /wp-content. To create a new Custom Page Template for a Page you must create a file using a plain text editor (e.g Notepad or TextWrangler).

Basically, create a php file, and put the following code in it:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Snarfer
*/
?>
```

> The above code is required and defines the snarfer.php file as the "Snarfer" Template. "Snarfer" may be replaced with most any text to change the name of the Page Template. The Template Name will appear in the WordPress Theme Editor for editing. For more information on Theme naming conventions see reserved Theme filenames for file names you should not use.

**By your request**

A [tutorial for adding fields to an existing options page](http://wpengineer.com/2139/adding-settings-to-an-existing-page-using-the-settings-api/).

Hope it will get you trough.

Comment: Well I know how to create different page layouts, I mean having different templates for the "POSTS" Page. I only can define one Posts Page in Settings > Reading.

Comment: That can be achieved by [`register_setting()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting), This allows you to add settings in existing option pages.

Comment: Or by [`add_settings_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field), more information about this in the [Settings_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Comment: Mh, could you describe or have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial in my answer. Hope it will help you.